# Ruby on Rails route with 2 parameters not routing correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Rails and to do that am making a small workout tracking app. I have a number of routes for my `ProgramsController`:

```
get "/programs/:user_id", to: "programs#show_all"
get "/programs/:user_id/new", to: "programs#new"
get "/programs/:user_id/program/:program_id", to: "programs#show"
post "/programs/:user_id/create", to: "programs#create"
get "/programs/:user_id/edit/:program_id", to: "programs#edit"
patch "/programs/:user_id/edit/:program_id", to: "programs#update"
delete "/programs/:user_id/programs/:program_id", to: "programs#destroy"
```

When I navigate to `/programs/1`, it executes the `show` action and renders the `show.html.erb` view, while it should be executing the `show_all` action and rendering the `show_all.html.erb` view. This seems like incorrect behavior to me, but I am new to Rails, so I am assuming I am missing something about how routes are resolved. How do I fix this routing error?

Comment: Are you 100% it hits the wrong action and there is nothing wrong with show_all method? What is your logs output when you navigate to `/programs/1`, especially the first two lines `Started GET "/programs/1" for ...` and `Processing by ....`

Comment: If you run `rake routes` do you see any duplicated routes that could be covering one another up?

Comment: Sounds like you have defined `resources :programs` somewhere above these routes. Routes work in a way that they are looking for first matching path in the routes and returns the controller and action for this path.

Comment: OK wow, I feel dumb. I had indeed, defined `resources :program` at the top of my `routes.rb` file and I had just been staring at things so long that I got tunnel vision. Thanks all.

Comment: I would think it better to use `resources` instead of typing this all out like this, nested resources can handle this effectively.

Comment: OK I will look into using resources. Why is this question getting downvoted though? It was an honest question with a clear example.

Answer (score -1):

[edariedl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3655580/edariedl) hit the nose on the head. I had defined `resources :programs` at the top of my routes.rb file and had just gotten tunnel vision and not noticed it.